# I keep getting this error help please..Syntax error on token ";", , expected

Tags: java

I am getting an error on this one says Syntax erroe on token ";", expected. what am i doing wrong or what am i missing, the error is coming from string input string. im trying to create where i can put in students grades then average the grades together so i am not sure if i'm even doing this right. Help please!!! Any ideas on how I can do this? Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;         //To hold the users score

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;  //For better style

 import java.text.DecimalFormat; //needed to format the Output


public class TestScore
{//begin class

    public static void main(String[] args)

    {//Begin main method



        //create the variables

     String inputString ;       // For reader's input

               DoubleScore1,      //Define DoubleScore 1

                DoubleScore2,     //Define DoubleScore 2

                DoubleScore3,    //Define DoubleScore 3

                AverageScore; //Define AverageScore



Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //To hold the users grade


DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00"); //format the scores



        //create keyboard for input

        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



        //Ask the user to input DoubleScore1

        inputString=

          JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter test score 1");



            // Convert the input to a double.

             DoubleScore1 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);



        //Ask the user to input DoubleScore

        inputString=

          JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter test score 2");



            // Convert the input to a double

        DoubleScore2 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);



        //Ask the user to input DoubleScore

        inputString=

          JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter test score 3");



            // Convert the input to a double

            DoubleScore3 = Double.parseDouble(inputString);







        //Calculate the average score for the tests

        AverageScore = ((DoubleScore1 + DoubleScore2 + DoubleScore3)/3);



        //Display Average test Score

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\t\nYour Double Score 1  is : "     +formatter.format(DoubleScore1)

                                      + "\t\nYour Double Score 2  is : " +formatter.format(DoubleScore2)

                                      + "\t\nYour Double Score 3  is : " +formatter.format(DoubleScore3)

                                      + "\t\nYour Average Score is: " +     formatter.format(AverageScore));

            //End the program.

          System.exit(0);



    }//End main method



}//end class`enter code here`
```

Comment: Way too much whitespace there

Comment: if you use a good `IDE`, it'd shown exactly where the error was and what the error was.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
String inputString ;       // For reader's input

               DoubleScore1,      //Define DoubleScore 1

                DoubleScore2,     //Define DoubleScore 2

                DoubleScore3,    //Define DoubleScore 3

                AverageScore; //Define AverageScore
```

should be

```
String inputString ,       // For reader's input

               DoubleScore1,      //Define DoubleScore 1

                DoubleScore2,     //Define DoubleScore 2

                DoubleScore3,    //Define DoubleScore 3

                AverageScore; //Define AverageScore
```

`;` will end the line so either next line has to declare that field again or use `,` to say it also same type like so.

```
               String inputString;       // For reader's input

               Double DoubleScore1,      //Define DoubleScore 1

                      DoubleScore2,     //Define DoubleScore 2

                     DoubleScore3,    //Define DoubleScore 3

                   AverageScore; //Define AverageScore
```

Comment: The type of DoubleScore1 is double not String.

Comment: @benzonico Apologies solved the error in syntax without rest of code :), see update.

Comment: @AbstractChaos Still, it's not right to repeat `Double` at each line if you keep the `,`.

Comment: Now it is giving me an error for DoubleScore1 = Double.parseDouble(inputString); says type mismatch cannot convert from double to java.lang.String

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the type of your variables DoubleScore:

```
double DoubleScore1;
```

Comment: But then don't end the line after `DoubleScore1` with a semi-colon `;`, end it with a coma `,` so you don't need to repeat `double` for the following variables.  Or is the `Double` type?